# Send ethernet raw packets on localhost in kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, ethernet, raw-sockets

I am implementing two kernel modules sending custom ethernet packet. It works when the two modules are in two different machines, but it does not when the destination address is the same as the interface used. 
This is my sending function, I create a packet which is something like this: 
`|MAC_ADDRESS | PROTO | DATA|`

```
int
eth_send(struct net_device* dev, uint8_t dest_addr[ETH_ALEN], uint16_t proto,
         const char* msg, size_t len)
{
  int            ret;
  unsigned char* data;

  struct sk_buff* skb = alloc_skb(ETH_FRAME_LEN, GFP_ATOMIC);

  skb->dev = dev;
  skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;

  skb_reserve(skb, ETH_HLEN);
  /*changing Mac address */
  struct ethhdr* eth = (struct ethhdr*)skb_push(skb, ETH_HLEN);
  skb->protocol = eth->h_proto = htons(proto);
  memcpy(eth->h_source, dev->dev_addr, ETH_ALEN);
  memcpy(eth->h_dest, dest_addr, ETH_ALEN);

  /* put the data and send the packet */
  if (len > ETH_DATA_LEN)
    len = ETH_DATA_LEN;

  data = skb_put(skb, len);

  if (memcmp(dev->dev_addr, dest_addr, ETH_ALEN * sizeof(uint8_t)) == 0) {
    // send to myself
  } else {
    // sending to other machine
    skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;
    ret = dev_queue_xmit(skb);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I cannot figure how to send it to myself. I tried using `netif_receive_skb` and `dev_loopback_xmit`, but they do not seem to work.
I register the `dev_add_pack` function to add a struct containing a `struct packet_type`, and inside assign the function to call when the packet containing the defined `PROTO` is received. As said, it works for packets from outside, but it does not for localhost.

How can I do that? Also a link explaining how these functions work would be appreciated.

Also, why is `dev_loopback_xmit(struct net *net, struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)` requiring also a sock and a net *, while inside it only uses the skb?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** this is what I use to send

```
int
eth_send(struct net_device* dev, uint8_t dest_addr[ETH_ALEN], uint16_t proto,
         const char* msg, size_t len)
{
  int             ret = 0;
  unsigned char*  data;
  struct sk_buff* skb = alloc_skb(ETH_FRAME_LEN, GFP_ATOMIC);

  skb->dev = dev;
  skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;

  skb_reserve(skb, ETH_HLEN);
  /*changing Mac address */
  struct ethhdr* eth = (struct ethhdr*)skb_push(skb, ETH_HLEN);
  skb->protocol = eth->h_proto = htons(proto);
  memcpy(eth->h_source, dev->dev_addr, ETH_ALEN);
  memcpy(eth->h_dest, dest_addr, ETH_ALEN);

  /* put the data and send the packet */
  if (len > ETH_DATA_LEN)
    len = ETH_DATA_LEN;

  data = skb_put(skb, len);
  memcpy(data, msg, len);

  if (memcmp(dev->dev_addr, dest_addr, ETH_ALEN) == 0) {
    skb->pkt_type = PACKET_LOOPBACK;
    netif_rx_ni(skb); // undefined behaviour?
  } else {
    ret = dev_queue_xmit(skb);
  }
  return !ret;
}
```

And this is the panic I get, my module is called kclient,

```
[  +0.000087] skbuff: skb_under_panic: text:ffffffff81833552 
len:-65485 put:-65535 head:ffff88030dabf800 data:ffff88020dacf7ff tail:0x32 end:0x6c0 dev:enp0s3
[  +0.241948] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  +0.105630] kernel BUG at /build/linux-jUC7gW/linux-4.4.0/net/core/skbuff.c:104!
[  +0.183770] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP
[  +0.080865] Modules linked in: kclient(OE) vboxsf binfmt_misc input_leds video vboxguest serio_raw isofs ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi autofs4 btrfs raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel mptspi aes_x86_64 lrw scsi_transport_spi gf128mul mptscsih glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd psmouse mptbase e1000
[  +0.967271] CPU: 2 PID: 2233 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OE   4.4.0-121-generic #145-Ubuntu
[  +0.192036] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[  +0.091681] task: ffff88030dd50000 ti: ffff88030f1ac000 task.ti: ffff88030f1ac000
[  +0.119018] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8172c1c4>]  [<ffffffff8172c1c4>] skb_panic+0x64/0x70
[  +0.025014] RSP: 0000:ffff88031f103d20  EFLAGS: 00010282
[  +0.001016] RAX: 000000000000008f RBX: ffff8800dadb2d00 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  +0.073327] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff88031f110558 RDI: ffff88031f110558
[  +0.151802] RBP: ffff88031f103d40 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000219
[  +0.156554] R10: 0000000000012400 R11: 0000000000000219 R12: ffff88030f32a800
[  +0.163420] R13: ffff88030dabf800 R14: 0000000000000032 R15: ffff88030dc36000
[  +0.175838] FS:  00007fd90ae3d700(0000) GS:ffff88031f100000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  +0.132958] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  +0.130855] CR2: 00005638cb656a18 CR3: 000000030fb62000 CR4: 0000000000040670
[  +0.161277] Stack:
[  +0.044096]  ffff88020dacf7ff 0000000000000032 00000000000006c0 ffff88030dc36000
[  +0.162723]  ffff88031f103d50 ffffffff8172cb8f ffff88031f103da0 ffffffff81833552
[  +0.188238]  ffff88031f110440 0000000000000002 ffff88030dc36000 ffff8800dadb2d00
[  +0.193325] Call Trace:
[  +0.060884]  <IRQ>
[  +0.043792]  [<ffffffff8172cb8f>] skb_push+0x3f/0x40
[  +0.099121]  [<ffffffff81833552>] packet_rcv+0xa2/0x450
[  +0.133466]  [<ffffffff81741c1c>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x74c/0xab0
[  +0.117920]  [<ffffffff810b7bb9>] ? update_curr+0x79/0x170
[  +0.110059]  [<ffffffff81741f98>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[  +0.100118]  [<ffffffff81742d98>] process_backlog+0xa8/0x150
[  +0.117832]  [<ffffffff817424e3>] net_rx_action+0x223/0x360
[  +0.137399]  [<ffffffff81087d66>] __do_softirq+0x106/0x2a0
[  +0.134271]  [<ffffffff81088073>] irq_exit+0xa3/0xb0
[  +0.064162]  [<ffffffff810af683>] scheduler_ipi+0x93/0x150
[  +0.127852]  [<ffffffff81051b3f>] smp_reschedule_interrupt +0x2f/0x40
[  +0.127852]  [<ffffffff8185143f>] reschedule_interrupt +0xbf/0xdo
                <EOI>
```

I am using a virtual machine to test, as you can see.

Comment: What is the device you use for sending packets to yourself? It should be "lo" not "eth0" or something like this. If you want to push some packet in RX path to the kernel you could use netif_rx() proc.

Comment: I did not wanted to use the "lo" interface, but the actual one used to send packets into the network. Eventually, I managed to send them with dev_loopback_xmit, but I don't understand how to set the struct dst_entry inside the skb, since every time I use that function, it triggers the WARN_OK(!skb(dst)). Any ideas/link where I can understand it? I could not find anything about this dst_entry...

Comment: Maybe you are digging too low in kernel sources? Try to use netif_rx() as I wrote.

Comment: I get a kenrel panic. I think the packet needs to be set differently, at least for localhost. I am going to update the question with the code I use to send. About receiving, I use dev_add_pack to link a callback to any message received having this protocol, for now I set it to a function that just prints "received", but it crash before getting there.

Comment: The skb_under_panic is called, so there is a problem with skb. I don't know if your custom protocol is properly maintained in linux network stack. I assume that you are using some custom proto above the ethernet layer. The kernel need to know how to maintenance this protocol - i.e. how many bytes it needs to pull from skb struct and what should be done with skb next.

Comment: I am simply building an packet, where I define a custom protocol number. I am pretty sure this is mantained correctly in the linux network stack since sending a message to another machine works perfectly. The panic gets created only when I send it to myself, there's something more I should do, which is probably done in dev_queue_xmit. The only way I managed to make it work is by reimplementing dev_loopback_submit without the WARN_ON. If you want to take a look, I have everything on https://github.com/esposem/kether2/blob/master/kernel/eth.c

Comment: Also, if you look at that file, you can see I had to manually skip the header length when I receive the packet, while this is automatically done when the packet it's received from the outside.

Comment: A few questions: why do you set ->pkt_type to PACKET_OUTGOING? Even for incoming packet? Is it necessary? I've written a few eth drivers and never set it. What is the value of "proto" passed to eth_send? Why don't you reserve any space for proto layer/header in skb?

Comment: PACKET_OUTGOING seems not to be necessary, but it does not solve the problem. proto is simply a number, something like 0xcafe, that is used to identify different kind of packet (I am using the same functions to implement a more complicated message passing). I don't think that putting it in the header or in the data part of the skb would change anything

Comment: Uhm.. it's very weird. I think that using `skb->pkt_type = PACKET_LOOPBACK; netif_rx_ni(skb);` could work, but there's something that produces some undefined behaviour. In fact, sometimes it was working, some other it crashed... And sometimes the eth->h_source was set to 00:00:00:00:00:00. The panic is more or less the same as the one I posted. I'll update the eth_send function above to show you my modifications. Not setting the pkt_type produces the same crash anyway

Comment: Once again - there is some problem with skb. How kernel should know what to do with your packet with ->proto==0xcafe? Did you modify the network stack to service your eth packets or you're only trying to do it in external module?

Comment: No, I am trying to do it in external module. I did not modify the network stack, I use dev_add_pack in eth_listen to register the callback to call when a message with that proto is received, nothing more

Comment: have you tried loopback_xmit() proc? It doesn't need sock struct.

Comment: I think loopback_xmit() is a static function inside loopback.c file, it's not declared in any header file. You mean copy all that code inside in a custom-made function in my file? I don't think it's a clean solution...